# Why fontfamily style does not apply to react native project

Tags: react-native, expo, font-family

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

export default function App() {
    const [isFontReady,
        setFontReady] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadFont() {
            return await Font.loadAsync({sans: require('./assets/fonts/sans.ttf')});
        }
        loadFont().then(() => {
            setFontReady(true)
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <View>
            {isFontReady && <Text style={{
                fontFamily: 'sans'
            }}>
                Silence is Golden.
            </Text>}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Drives me crazy; I can't find the reason why fontFamily style ex: Tahoma has got no effect on a font?
The code looks OK and I even restarted the project by typing >'expo start -c' and reinstalled the packages but no change!

Comment: If you right click and get info on the font, you can see the real name. I think the issue is the real name of the font is Sans not sans even if the file is this name.

can you try `fontFamily: 'Sans'`

Comment: Thank you! I can believe problem solved :'(

Comment: This fix your issue :) ?